# Dagger 2 Component not generating Dagger Prefixed Classes for building

Tags: java, android, maven, intellij-idea, dagger-2

I am new to Dagger 2 and am trying out the Dagger 2 Coffee Example in IntelliJ and it seems that is does not generate a DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee (It should be generating it) even though I followed the code example for Dagger 2 in github closely.

```
Public class CoffeeApp {
    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = {DripCoffeeModule.class})
    public interface Coffee {

        CoffeeMaker maker();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){


        Coffee coffee = DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee.builder().build();
    }
}
```

Here is my pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tim.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Dagger2Experiment</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <slf4j-api.version>1.7.12</slf4j-api.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <name>sonatype-repo</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-api.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I have tried various solution from the topic below but nothing seems to work:

I have also added jar file to my application buildpath dagger-2.0.1.jar in your application's runtime and dagger-compiler-2.0.1.jar in your build at compile time.

**Update**
I used DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee.builder().build() in the code snippet above since I edited my code to follow the code example in Dagger 2's github below after I couldn't find the constructor. Link below:

https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/examples/simple/src/main/java/coffee/CoffeeApp.java

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: unbalanced braces on main()?

Comment: oops thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit it since it was a copy & paste mistake. The braces are correct in my code :)

Comment: Try not declaring `dagger-compiler` as optional. I had problems using gradle `provided` for `dagger-compiler` in android and setting it to `compile` fixed it.

Comment: Tried that but no changes so far and still can't find a Dagger prefixed constructor. Do I need some android related depedencies? That's the only difference between my pom.xml and the pom.xml on google's github.

Comment: dagger should not need android to work, but you can try their example to see if it works on your computer, to discard problems on your setup

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
Yep, You caught me skimming the question.  I failed to read your code example otherwise I would have seen the pom.xml wasn't the only issue.

1. I'm assuming your DripCoffeeModule is annotated correctly and has no parameters in its constructor so that you don't need to specify this in building the Component. E.g. :

   ```
   @Module

   public DripCoffeeModule {

   //Uses default constructor

   }
   ```
2. I've not seen the Component implemented as an inner class before but I'm betting that Dagger won't treat this any different in terms of instantiating.  (I would recommend moving it out of CoffeeApp class.)  The naming, however, would be incorrect.  Instead of

   ```
   DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee.builder().build();
   ```

You have to follow the naming convention defined by Dagger.  From the section titled **Building the Graph** on Dagger's website:

> The implementation has the same name as the interface prefixed with *Dagger*.

So you need to modify the line to:

```
DaggerCoffee.builder().build();
```

or you can use the convenience method:

```
DaggerCoffee.create();
```

If I'm wrong about number 1, then you will need to construct your Module as well like so:

```
DaggerCoffee.builder().dripCoffeeModule(new DripCoffeeModule()).build();
```

**Original**

Move the compiler from the dependencies section into the compiler section.  From the Dagger 2 official site.

> In a Maven project, one would include the runtime in the dependencies section of your pom.xml, and **the dagger-compiler artifact as a dependency of the compiler plugin:**

For example:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look back at it. I tried what you suggested and there was no DaggerCoffee constructor. The interesting thing is I looked at the Dagger 2's github code and made changes accordingly.

You can see the DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee.builder().build() below:

https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/examples/simple/src/main/java/coffee/CoffeeApp.java

Comment: I'll update my post to provide more context on it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I chased a similar problem then realized I was not importing the @Component interface generated implementation. Once I added the import, using the same package path as my interface, my code compiled and worked.